# ASP.NET Core 2.0 Identity

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.0

I've found quite a few tutorials for ASP.NET Identity but they don't seem to relate to ASP.NET Core 2.0 Identity. I'm not sure if this is because the Identity component is a different version or not.

I want to change the table names, add additional properties and change the keys to integers.

I'm looking for some direction that specifically relates to ASP.NET Core 2.0 Identity, all the older information seems to relate to older versions.

For reference, I've been using [this post so](https://medium.com/@goodealsnow/asp-net-core-identity-3-0-6018fc151b4) far, but it leaves me with loads of errors regarding integers in the controller class and suggests customization isn't really possible...

Comment: What does your `IdentityDbContext` look like?

Answer (score -1):

> add additional properties and change the keys to integers.

```
public class User : IdentityUser<int>
{
    public string MyCustomProperty { get; set; }
}
```

I'm not aware how you can change Identity's table names though.

[Also, you don't need to use Identity at all](https://weblogs.asp.net/jeff/no-you-don-t-need-to-use-asp-net-identity)

Also Identity system uses Entity Framework Core by default, if you need something else, some different ORM library or third party client to work with your data you need to adapt it for your needs.

See [Custom storage providers for ASP.NET Core Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-custom-storage-providers)

Here is [reference on how to port Identity from 1.x to 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/identity-2x). So you can just take the tutorial you have found and port it according to this.

Comment: To further clarify your point about needing Identity at all, I only need simple login/logout functionality, would you recommend not using it all and implementing my own functionality?

Comment: That would be re-inventing the wheel, as the identity already provides hashing passwords and things like user groups(roles) etc. It's up to you though. If you want something own you can, but it will cost you time.

Comment: Also login, register is pretty simple to make with identity once you get a grasp ;)

Comment: Here is somewhat updated docs for using Identity: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?tabs=visual-studio%2Caspnetcore2x as well as authenticating users.

Comment: I think you should create your own system if you need complete control on how things work it's up to you if you want to bother with it. If you're lazy and want to just focus on the product and have authentication and authorization 
 out of the box then Identity gives you that and I think you can configure it to some degree. The only disadvantage is you have to learn it.

Comment: I think I need to be a bit more ruthless with the controller class and strip out what I don't need. Unfortunately it doesn't seem the latest version of Identity allows you to change the keys to integers with your suggestion.

Comment: It should work. Make sure to create a migration it should appear as INT in your database.